# how to install librsync-0.9.7 manually?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

They give some instruction in [here](https://github.com/librsync/librsync).As I downloaded tar.gz file I extract and go to that repository.then I run `./configure` cmd and it occurs this error `bash: ./configure: Permission denied`.In previous I never install any library manually always use apt-get to install any software so I might be wrong to flowing there instruction.

Comment: What location did you extract it to exactly?

Comment: I have a partition called PROJECT.In there I extract it.

Comment: What is the filesystem of the partition? if it is a non-*nix partition (e.g. FAT or NTFS) then it might not support Linux execute permissions.

Comment: I got it.My partition tyep is HPFS/NTFS so what should I do now??In which type my partition should have transfer.

Comment: There are ways to force NTFS to mount with execute permissions, but afaik not on a per-file basis. The easiest solution would be to use your regular home directory for this task.

Comment: I copy my folder in my home directory but still have same problem.Any solution @steeldriver.

Comment: Don't just copy it (the permissions are already lost): start over and extract it again from the tar.gz file inside your home directory

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, your problem is when you run `./configure`, your user needs more permissions!
In this case the best way is just run it `sudo ./configure` and enter your password. 
It will run your command as an administrator which solve your problem with permissions.

This word `sudo` will be often used if you want to be comfortable with command line.
Please comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: As you say sudo that's why I login with my root and run it but still the same problem.